# FlowType.JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm attempting to use [FlowType.JS](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) on [this site](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test).

I have the following in the head:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/wp-content/themes/blueduck3/js/flowtype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('body').flowtype({
    minimum   : 500,
    maximum   : 1200,
    minFont   : 12,
    maxFont   : 40,
    fontRatio : 30
  });
</script>
```

However, the #content P, H1, and the #menu A, p.bookings, div.opening-hours do not scale downward when I make the viewport smaller.

Does anyone have an idea why?  Thanks.

Comment: please share jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: Try inside document.ready

Comment: @Sudharsan: I tried inside document.ready but the issue remained.  I think the issue is caused by having two versions of jQuery, but I am unable to resolve this - see my comment to Rohan Kumar's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please enter this code, and make sure flowtype.js is called before the code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(document).ready(function() {
            /*$j('body').flowtype({
                minimum   : 500,
                maximum   : 1200,
                minFont   : 12,
                maxFont   : 20
              });
              */
            $j("body").flowtype({
                minFont: 16,
                maxFont: 40,
                fontRatio: 65
            });
            $j("#heading").flowtype({
                fontRatio: 36
            });
            $j("#content p").flowtype({
                minFont: 12,
                maxFont : 22,
                fontRatio: 20
            });
            $j("#menu a").flowtype({
                minFont: 16,
                fontRatio: 5                    
            });
            $j("p.bookings").flowtype({
                minFont: 11,
                fontRatio: 30
            });
            $j("div.opening-hours").flowtype({
                minFont: 18,
                fontRatio: 30
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Also, please note the following lines mentioned on the plugin website.

```
Line-height
```

> ```
> In v1.0 of FlowType, we made the plugin set a specific line-height in pixels. We received many statements that setting a specific line-height is very dangerous. So, what did we do? We removed support for line-height in v1.1.
>
> What do I do now? It's quite simple: use unitless line-height in your CSS. It will make automatically make changes based on whatever the font-size. Here's an example of what we suggest for line-height:
> fontRatio : 30;
> ```

If you have further issue, then please mention the link to your jsfiddle code.

Comment: Thanks Devang.  It went over my head that I had to call flowtype on the elements in question.

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. And yes, Line height is the major issue for cross browsers, so they have deliberately removed line-height option from the latest version of flowtype.js

Comment: Hi.  I can't get the navigation menu on the left to scale down when reducing the width of the view port.  I have 
`$j("#nav ul li a").flowtype({
  minFont: 10,
  maxFont: 18;
  fontRatio: 30                    
});`

Comment: Hi, can you please give me the screenshot of the website which you want to achieve when reducing the width of the view port. I am confused with what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi.  Sure.  [Here](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/font-size.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are including 2 jquery versions `jquery-2.1` and `jquery 1.6.4` and ther is confliction in both versions. You can see it in console.

Use [jquery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for no confliction

Comment: Thanks for your help Rohan.  I added `$.noConflict();` before `$('body').flowtype({` and the issue remains.  Is that the correct place to put it?

Comment: It should just after adding a version of jquery.

Comment: I'm confused Rohan.  I don't have great control over where Wordpress plugins place their calls to include jquery.  Can you have a look at [my site](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/) please?